# Apply _Layout.cshtml to .html page using ASP.net Core

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core

I need to know if it is possible to use layout.cshtml in html file.

Basically, I want html page to have a master page i.e, layout.cshtml. If it is possible, please guide how?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is for some one, who does not know asp.net core. But they want to use asp.net layout. They want to apply master pages to their html pages. They will add html pages to wwwroot folder and add some code in html to use layout. Is this request possible in asp.net core?

Comment: Why not simply convert it to a Razor page? They're extremely simple.

Comment: I totally agree with @mason. But the requirement is to use html pages.

Comment: Then no, I am not aware of a built in way to do this. You could probably create something easily enough that does it, just create an HTML helper that takes in the name/path to a .HTML file and grabs the HTML and puts it in the Razor page. Of course if you're going to go to all the trouble of that....you might as well just use Razor .cshtml files.

Comment: Or maybe they also want that HTML because it has a dependency and it can not be unchanged? Anyways, you could also create a copy of that file as cshtml if that's the case, otherwise cshtml is just html with the power of more control over the dom elements.